# How to store menu items in an effective way?

Tags: html, html-lists

On my school project we have to build a Website for a Restaurant, so, a simple digital menu, for now, I have to make it static, so no databases. But I run into a problem. Let me explain. I divided the food into categories(eg: drinks, food). I have created a simple card for every category with an image, so let's take for example the "food" category. When a user presses the "See Menu" Button I made it so this list shows up in the form of a Pop-Up. Here it is:
[image]

BUT, here is a portion of the of how I actually save the menu data:

```
<div class="menu">
<h2>Our Menu</h2>
<ul>
     <li>
         <label>
             <input type="checkbox" name="">
             <span class="icon"></span>
             <span class="list">Fried Fish With Souce</span>
         </label>
     </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

As you can see, I have to write lots of HTML Tags contained within the < li > tags for EVERY item, there will actually have to be written the price and description. I don't have a problem with writing all the items, but I want to do it only once AND the biggest problem is that for now, I write everything for the menu INSIDE the index.html file with the display: none; property set on the menu until the "See Menu" Button is pressed. My question is, how can I store the data in an effective way so I can even modify it in the future. I want to use the same style of menu, but the contents and number of elements must change from category to category. I heard something about XML, but I don't know if it's useful in this case. I hope that the answer to this question will help someone in the future too. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll store the data itself on an array of objects (maybe on local storage) and populate it on document load, creating the HTML by JS.
something like

```
const storedMenu = [{name: "Fried Fish With Souce", checked: false}, 
                    {name:"anotherName", checked: false}]
```

and then the populate funtion something like this:

```
storedMenu.reduce((accumulator, currentItem) => {
    accumulator += `<label> 
         <input type="checkbox" name="">
         <span class="icon"></span>
         <span class="list">${currentItem.name}</span>
     </label>`
}, '' )
```

I think this solves your issue, if you need more information or more realistic code, just let me know

Documentation to [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: I knew that there was an answer somewhere, I just didn't know the answer. I am going to try and implement this, in case I need help, I'm going to comment here. You saved me from learning PHP from scratch. Thanks a lot!

Comment: a pleasure to help, let me know if you need any more help or clarification

Comment: Hey, I need just a little bit of help and that's all. After adding your code I had to adapt it and this is the result [link](https://imgur.com/adEgocI) . The source code is this [link](https://pastebin.com/LBn5r2X9) . As you can see, the document.write creates sort of a new page, but I want the style inside the css file to be applied to the tags and to maintain the original index.html page, not to overwrite it. The function showMenu() of the JavaScript is called by the onclick="" event on a button. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Some years ago a problem similar to this was a prompt to me to start learning PHP.

Try it - PHP is the language to dynamically create HTML. In PHP you can create templates of elements of the page and then include them in another page. Data can be stored in arrays and retrieved between pages using sessions.

Lots to learn... You could start at [codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-php), or just google "PHP course".

Comment: Well, I never heard of PHP. I'll get straight to learning then. Thanks mate!